# How to start an Alfresco Workflow through Javascript adding a resource

Tags: javascript, alfresco, activiti

Starting using a rule and a simple javascript in Alfresco is quite easy but i'm stuck on trying to start a workflow through javascript adding a resource.

My goal is to add the document (or documents) used to start the flow, so i can obtain a reference in the "OW_ATTACHMENTS" of the Alfresco BPM of the Alfresco WorkDesk.
I've tried many times with the bpm:workflowpagckage or bpm:package with no luck....help!

Edit:

```
  function startWorkflow(name,docNode)
{    
    var workflow = actions.create("start-workflow");
    workflow.parameters["bpm:workflowPackage"] = docNode;
    workflow.parameters.workflowName = "activiti$AdHocactivitiTimer";
    workflow.parameters["bpm:assignee"] = people.getPerson("admin");
    workflow.parameters["bpm:workflowDescription"] = "test";
    workflow.parameters["bpm:workflowPriority"] = "2";
    workflow.parameters["bpm:sendEMailNotifications"] = true;
    workflow.parameters["initiator"] = people.getPerson("admin"); 
    var today = new Date();
    var duedate = today.getDate() + 1; 
    workflow.parameters["bpm:workflowDueDate"] = duedate;
    workflow.execute(document);
}

function main()
{    
    var docNode = search.findNode(document.nodeRef); 
    var name = document.name;  
        startWorkflow(name,docNode); 
}


main();
```

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bpm:package or bpm_package is not available before start.
So what happens you're document is added to bpm_package.

And in your workflow you can access **bpm_package** as a variable. And with **bpm_package.addNode(doc);** you can add nodes.

These nodes can be found through search/childbynamepath/xpath etc.

If you don't use the action the other way is:

```
var workflowAction = workflow.getDefinitionByName('activiti$AdHocactivitiTimer');
var package= workflow.createPackage();
package.addNode(document);
workflowAction.startWorkflow(package, parameters);
```

Comment: Malik thanks for your answer...i didn't get why if i use bpm_package in my javascript it tells me :ReferenceError: "bpm_package" is not defined. I've seen it only used in the models, not in the js associated to rules...am i wrong?

Comment: Like I said, there is no package yet in the beginning. So when you start the workflow it creates one. Or you need to create the package yourself. the bpm_package is only accessible in the JS in workflow. there it's being filled. Look at: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/WorkflowAdministration#Process_Data

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish the same thing but can't make it work with your solution. My code is almost exactly the same (with less parameters), I created the package as you wrote and added the doc to it. My workflow is correctly created and assigned but when I access it, the items element is empty. Do I need to add anything in the bmpn file? No errors in the console.

Comment: So you've added: var package= workflow.createPackage();
package.addNode(document);

Comment: var wfdef = workflow.getDefinitionByName("activiti$reviewNewFile");
var wfpackage = workflow.createPackage();
wfpackage.addNode(document);
wfdef.startWorkflow(wfpackage,wfparams);

Comment: So your document is surely not null right? And if it isn't, then can't help you mate, it's getting to detailed. Ofcourse I do consulting and can debug what you've done on a hourly fee.

Comment: nop, document is not null because I put document.name in workflowDescription param and it's correcly displayed. I'll keep looking. Thanks for your time.