# Alfresco - Run a custom workflow after adding file

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

I need to implement my own action but I have no idea how to do this. 
The goal is to make a rule on a prepared folder.  When someone puts a file to it, alfresco is starting a new custom made workflow automatically, with attached file. 
 How to create that kind of function? Where to begin? I'm new to Alfresco.

Greetings, Rafał

Comment: Create a Rule on the folder, and have it run a javascript file that starts the workflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, @Gagravarr is right

Create a rule on folder
In perform action you have to execute a script file which will be rest in your Data Dicionary/ Scripts folder

place this test.js file in Scripts folder and create a rule and in Perform Action execute script and select test.js file and create rule.

Sample script file for starting a workflow
test.js `activiti$test_wf` replace with your custom workflow id.

```
function startWorkflow()
{
    var workflowAction = workflow.getDefinitionByName("activiti$test_wf");
    var package= workflow.createPackage();

    var wfparams = new Array();
    wfparams["model_prefix:req_props_name"] = value2;

    wfparams["bpm:assignee"] = people.getPerson("ADMIN");
    workflowAction.startWorkflow(package, wfparams);
    }

}

startWorkflow();
```

Comment: and refer this community question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156819/how-to-start-an-alfresco-workflow-through-javascript-adding-a-resource

Answer (score 1):

You should also look into behaviours, which are basically an extension point to Alfresco.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/dev-extension-points-behaviors.html